# Dynamically allocating 2D int array

Tags: c++, arrays

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong in the following code?

```
int* a = NULL;   
int* b = NULL;   
a = new int[map->mapSize.width];
b = new int[map->mapSize.height];

layer->tileGids = new int[a][b];
```

Here's what the code uses:

```
typedef struct _size {
    int width, height;
} size;

class Map {
    size mapSize;
}

class Layer {
    int * tileGids;
}
```

EDIT: Compiler-Errors (in line 6 of the first bit of code):

- error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type|
- error: 'b' cannot appear in a constant-expression|

**Solution:**

I have decided to accept lightalchemist's answer. In essence, what works for me is use a vector instead of the array. Vector manages the memory for you and hence is a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: -1. What happens when you try to compile this? Do you get an error from the compiler or a problem when you run it? You must tell us what symptoms you are getting.

Comment: Apologies for my bad answer :P I removed it :)

Comment: And also, you've used `size` before you've defined it. Your code requires a lot of improvement.

Comment: The code after "Here's what the code uses:" was just copy-paste from a number of files, sorry about the wrong order. I've updated my question to fix that and to include the compiler-errors.

Comment: I believe it's time to take back the downvotes since the question looks fixed  to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your variables "a" and "b" are pointers. Your code:
layer->tileGids = new int[a][b]
is the root cause of the problem.

I'm trying to guess your intention here and I think what you are trying to do is make layer.tileGids a 2 dimension array to reference a "grid" of size (mapSize.Width, mapSize.height) so that you can refer to each "cell" in the grid using layer.tileGids[x][y].

If you are indeed trying to create a 2 dimension array, there are 2 methods to do it.

**Method 1:**

```
class Layer {
int ** tileGids; // NOTE the "**" to indicate tileGids is a pointer to pointer i.e. 2D array.
}
```

To initialize it:

```
int width = map->mapSize.width;
int height = map->mapSize.height;
layer.tileGids = new int*[width]; // NOTE the "int*" to indicate tileGids is a new array of pointers to int.
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) // Initialize each element in layer.tileGids[] to be a pointer to int.
{
  layer.tileGids[i] = new int[height];
}
```

Now you can access the items in layer.tileGids using:

```
int value = layer.tileGids[x][y] // where 0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height
```

To deallocate this data structure, similar to how you allocate it, you need to deallocate each dynamically allocated array in each "row":

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
      delete [] layer.tileGids[i]; // Deallocate each row.
    }

delete [] layer.tileGids; // Deallocate "array" to the pointers itself.
```

**Method 2:**

Now another easier, less messy method (avoid pointers) is to use the C++ vector class. You need to make the following changes:

```
#include <vector>
class Layer {
  vector<vector<int> > tileGids; // Note the space at "<int> >".
}
```

To initialize:

```
int width = map->mapSize.width;
int height = map->mapSize.height;
layer.tileGids = vector<vector<int> >(width, vector<int>(height, 0));  // Initialize all entries to 0.
```

To access the elements:

```
int value = layer.tileGids[x][y]; // Where 0 <= x < width and 0 <= y < height
```

Note that for the second method using vectors, you do not have to do any memory cleanup as is required in the first method because the vector will automatically take care of it.  However, because a vector can grow dynamically i.e. you can add items to it, you lose the safety of having a fixed size array i.e. someone could accidentally increase the size of your grid if you use the vector method but if he tries to do that when you intialized it using the first method above an error will occur and you will immediately know that something is wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I will go with the `vector` as that seems to be safer than the 2D array for now. Can I ask again, do I or do I not need to call any clear or similar method in the destructor of my layer class?

Comment: Hi. If you are using the vector method you don't need to do any memory management unless you dynamically allocate your vector object itself. Specifically, answering your qn, if you use my code above as it is, you don't need to call "clear" or anything that might suggest deallocating memory. I will update my answer to provide code to deallocate memory using the "pointer" approach.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I'm gonna stick with your vector code.

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a pointer for initializing the size of an array. Others have now mentioned this.

This post (it's not mine) seems like it might help you: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2003/07/23/allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-c/

You should also consider doing the allocation in the class Layer's constructor and then deleting the memory in it's destructor (i.e. RAII - resource acquisition is initialization). This is considered good style.

Finally, you might consider using continuous memory and a custom indexing scheme, which you could easily use Layer to encapsulate. This of course depends upon how big things will get. The bigger they get the better the case for continuous memory becomes.

This should give you a flavor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
   const size_t ROWS = 5; 
   const size_t COLS = 2; 
   const size_t size = ROWS*COLS;

   int* arr = new int[size];

   int i = 0;
   for ( size_t r = 0 ; r < ROWS; ++r )
   {
      for (size_t c = 0; c < COLS; ++c )
      {
         arr[r*COLS+c] = i++;
      }
   }

   for ( int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
   {
      std::cout << arr[j] << std::endl;
   }

   delete [] arr;
}
```

Comment: "You should also consider doing the allocation in the class Layer's constructor and then deleting the memory in it's destructor (i.e. RAII - resource acquisition is initialization). This is considered good style." - Thanks! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong in the following code?

A lot. You're allocating two single arrays (a "row array" and a "column array", not what you need), and then you try to do something strange.

---

Generally you can't (strictly speaking) dynamically allocate a 2D array in C++ (because the type system would still need the type, along with the dimensions, to be known at compile time). You can emulate it with an array of arrays or so, but the best way is to allocate an 1D array:

```
int width=5;

std::vector<int> tab(width*height);
```

and then access the element by calculating the coordinates manually:

```
// access the element (1,2)
tab[1 + 2*width] = 10;
```

This way you're essentially interpreting a 1D array as a 2D array (with performance equal to static 2D arrays).

Then it's best to wrap the indexing with a class for convenience; `boost::multi_array` also has this done for you already.

Comment: you can't have a 2D array in C++?  I believe you're msitaken, or should claify what you mean. `new char[30][20]` results in a 2D array.

Comment: int main(){int** arr2 = new int[10][10];} gives the following error, which is expected.  

error: cannot convert ‘int (*)[10]’ to ‘int**’ in initialization

Comment: @MooingDuck: You can have a 2D array, but the number of rows must be a compile-time constant. Only the number of columns in each row is allowed to be dynamic. This is because the compiler needs to know the stride (the length of each row) in order to calculate the offsets properly when indexing into non-zero rows.

Comment: Well, it results in a dynamic array of static arrays. The first parameter cannot be dynamic here because the type system without VLAs wouldn't support it. I see your point, but I wouldn't call it a "dynamic 2D array". :)

Comment: @CraigWright an array is not a pointer (even though it can be converted to one). You can't point to an array with a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

a and b are `int*` here:

```
layer->tileGids = new int[a][b];
```

Perhaps you meant to say this?

```
layer->tileGids = new int[*a][*b];
```